# Flutter ListWidget Twice Adds and Removes items

Tags: flutter

I need to add an entry to the list.

Only the first input works, but starting with second and after I see multiple items added to list instead of latest one.

Please see the screenshot below.

[image]

Issue: I added 2 items to list, but the list shows 4 items where some items are duplicates.

When I remove the item, all items except the first one are removed twice.

Code:

```
   import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  static const String title = 'Flutter Sample';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: title,
        home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(title)),
            body: const MyStatefulWidget()));
  }
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({super.key});
  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  bool light = true;
  final List<String> names = <String>[];
  TextEditingController nc = TextEditingController();
  void addItemToList() {
    setState(() {
      names.add(nc.text);
    });
  }

  void deleteItemFromList() {
    setState(() {
      names.removeLast();
    });
  }

  clearInput() {
    setState(() {
      nc.text = "";
    });
  }

  bool x = false;

  setInput() {
    setState(() {
      x != x;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> getList() {
      List<Widget> ListWidget = names.map((p) => Text(p)).toList();
      return ListWidget;
    }

    Widget test1 = Text("Hello Flutter");
    Widget test2 = Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: TextField(
            enabled: true,
            controller: nc,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(), labelText: 'Name')));
    Widget test3 = SwitchListTile(
        value: x,
        onChanged: (bool value) {
          setState(() {
            x = value;
          });
        });
    Widget buttons = SizedBox(
        width: 1000,
        height: 30,
        child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              Expanded(
                  child: TextButton(
                      onPressed: clearInput, child: Text('ClearInput'))),
              Expanded(
                  child:
                      TextButton(onPressed: addItemToList, child: Text('Add'))),
              Expanded(
                  child: TextButton(
                      onPressed: deleteItemFromList, child: Text('Remove')))
            ]));

    Widget mylist = ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
        itemCount: names.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Container(
              child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: getList()));
        });
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
            body: SingleChildScrollView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                          child: SingleChildScrollView(
                              child: Column(
                                  mainAxisAlignment:
                                      MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                test1,
                                test2,
                                test3,
                                buttons,
                                mylist
                              ])))
                    ]))));
  }
}
```

Please help

Thank You

Comment: does it remove and twice, too?

Comment: yes, I updated the above question. All items except the 1st one are removed twice as well. Thank You

Comment: can you properly format your code

Comment: I formatted the code with Dart Format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to optimise the code.

The problem was the `getList` function was inside the `Build`. Also you are adding a single item every time in the List.builder.

Here is the optimised code. Hope this helps.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  static const String title = 'Flutter Sample';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: title,
        home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(title)),
            body: const MyStatefulWidget()));
  }
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({super.key});
  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  bool light = true;
  List<String> names = [];
  TextEditingController nc = TextEditingController();
  void addItemToList() {
    setState(() {
      names.add(nc.text);
      getList();
    });
  }

  List<Widget> getList() {
    listWidget = [];
    listWidget = names.map((p) => Text(p)).toList();
    return listWidget;
  }

  void deleteItemFromList() {
    setState(() {
      if (names.isEmpty) return;
      names.removeLast();
    });
  }

  clearInput() {
    setState(() {
      nc.text = "";
    });
  }

  bool x = false;

  setInput() {
    setState(() {
      x != x;
    });
  }

  List<Widget> listWidget = [];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget test1 = const Text("Hello Flutter");
    Widget test2 = Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: TextField(
            enabled: true,
            controller: nc,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(), labelText: 'Name')));
    Widget test3 = SwitchListTile(
        value: x,
        onChanged: (bool value) {
          setState(() {
            x = value;
          });
        });
    Widget buttons = SizedBox(
      width: 1000,
      height: 30,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Expanded(
              child: TextButton(
                  onPressed: clearInput, child: const Text('ClearInput'))),
          Expanded(
              child: TextButton(
                  onPressed: addItemToList, child: const Text('Add'))),
          Expanded(
            child: TextButton(
              onPressed: deleteItemFromList,
              child: const Text('Remove'),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );

    Widget mylist = ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
        itemCount: names.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return listWidget[index];
        });
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: <Widget>[test1, test2, test3, buttons, mylist],
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```